# Camera on design view does not show the correct position in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a character and I attached a camera to him, I want a top view so I have 90 angles rotation on x.

In my game view everything is correct, the character is on the center.

[image]

but in my design view the character is on the left right corner,

[image]

I cannot understand why this is happening. Any idea?

Comment: did you attach the camera to the character or main camera?

Comment: @mehow I dont have a main camera, this is the "main" camera.

Answer (score 1):

Probably your Game View is exactly the same as Scene View in the very first frame but you can't see it because it changes in the next `Update` cycles.

That behavior can only happen when **you have one or more scripts changing your camera's `transform` properties such as `position` or `rotation`.**

Look into your active game objects scripts (including the camera object itself). Somewhere you are changing its properties.

I hope this is enough to help you solve this problem. I would need to look into your project scripts to  identify where is the problem and probably I wouldn't want to because depending on your project size it might take a lot of time :)